# How do you execute custom code when terminating a program in linux with Ctrl + C (SIGINT)

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi4

So I am doing a project with a Raspberry Pi 4 where I need to change a Pin from low to high (pin 23) only after confirming that a different pin is in fact high. The problem is that if I do it before the control pin is high, I will burn the FPGA connected to pin 23. What I am trying to do is to have Linux change pin 23 to low whenever my program exits regardless of how it is done, but especially when exiting with Ctrl+C or closing the terminal.

I have no idea where to even begin solving this.

Comment: You can set up a signal handler for SIGINT/SIGHUP to override the default behavior which terminates your program. (SIGKILL would be a different matter however. There is nothing you can do about that.) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within conforming C++, then, as far as I know, you are limited to using [std::signal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) to set up a signal handler.

The problem here is that, as the link shows, the function you set up as the signal handler is *heavily* restricted in what it actually can do. In fact, the only thing I feel comfortable suggesting is: Set a value in some `std::atomic` type and then return. Then in your main loop check if the value is set, and exit correctly if it is - so the actual work is done in the main thread, not in the handler.

If you want to do more in the signal handler - for example, I have a multi-threaded program where the threads communicate through passing messages, so a clean shutdown is done by passing a shutdown message to the main message queue - then I can suggest these POSIX functions:

As one of the first things in your main thread (specifically before setting up any other threads), make a signal set and mask (turn off) those for the main thread - all future threads you make inherit the mask from their parent, so they also start with those signals ignored:

```
int main()
{
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGCONT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    int err = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr);
    if (err != 0)
        // Report error
```

Then set up a new thread that will just sit there and sleep, waiting for signals to show up, and pass it the set you just made - the point is for it to wait for exactly the signals you just turned off in other threads.

```
void sigHandler(sigset_t const *const set, Controller *ctrl)
{
    int sig;

    while (true)
    {
        sigwait(set, &sig);

        switch (sig)
        {
        case SIGTERM:   // Terminate
        case SIGCONT:   // Continue (aka. restart) - both are used by systemctrl when restarting jobs
            ctrl->send(CtrlMsg::StopMsg{});
            [[fallthrough]];
        case SIGUSR1:   // User signal 1 is used to tell the signal handler to stop
            return;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I respond to SIGTERM and SIGCONT by shutting down, while SIGUSR1 is used by the main thread to tell the signal handler that we are shutting down. So the main function has this near the end:

```
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1); // Tell signal handle thread to stop
    signalHandler.join();  // <- this is the signal handler thread
```

You can read up on all the POSIX commands here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sigaddset

The benefit of doing all this over a fairly simple `std::signal` is that the signal handler set up by that will be executed by whichever thread is active, interrupting whatever it is currently doing. This (especially in a multi-threaded program) means that you have no idea where it will be executed - and that is a big part of why the handler is so limited in what it can do.

Whereas with `pthread_sigmask` and `sigwait` you know exactly where the signal will be handled, and the state of the thread that will do the handling. Thus all the restrictions fall away and you can do whatever you want (within the limits of C++).

Comment: That's perfect, it's exactly what I was looking for, because it is a multithreaded program I'm using to parse images from a camera and pass them to an FPGA.